# tumblr_client post function hash passed as array

Tags: ruby, tumblr

I am trying to use the tumblr_client gem to post images to a tumblr, but when I use the photo function as it is described in the examples I get an error saying that I am passing a Array not a Hash.

This is the line that breaks it

```
client.photo("blahblah.tumblr.com", {:data => "path.jpg", :tag => "tags"})
```

and the error I get is

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/tumblr_client-0.8.2/lib/tumblr/helpers.rb:17:in `validate_options': undefined method `keys' for [[:data, "path.jpg"], [:tag, "tags"]]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

I'm pretty sure i am passing a hash but uh... anyone got any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tumblr client is expecting the :data value to be an array, eg:

```
client.photo("codingjester.tumblr.com", {:data => ['/path/to/pic.jpg', '/path/to/pic.jpg']})
```

Check out [the tumblr_client README](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr_client) for more examples